# Unity double mouse click input event receive

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mouseevent, mouse, mouseclick-event

I'm making a 2D topdown shooter in Unity (version 5.6.0b3 64-bit) and I have a problem with receive mouse input properly, especially mousewheel.

I'm using mousewheel for switching weapons.

I have a problem with registering mouse input.

Code for my mouse:

```
if(Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel")>0)
{
Debug.Log("Mousewheel Up");
}

if(Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel")<0)
{
Debug.Log("Mousewheel Down");
}
```

After first launching game in main menu in console I can see it detecting corretly

[image]

But after starting game and loading scene its starting to act weird and double registering mouse wheel moving:

[image]

And by this bug switching weapon not working corretly (it double switching it, missing one in the middle)
for example i have 3 weapons, from 1 it switches to 3.

Also it spawn 2 explosions on 1 right click (should be 1)

I don't know what is going on, I appreciate every help.

Comment: Hey, can you share the full script for the Mouse input?

Comment: Hello, there not too much more Mouse input on the script. The mouse input fragments are integrated with player controller script. I don't think that mouse input in the script have something to do with it. I have doubled every mouse button too. In my script I have only mouse aiming by Screen to World Point and shooting       if( Input.GetButton("Fire1") && GameController.pause == false && GameController.game == true && GameController.shop == false) {
  wep.Shoot();
  }

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague but I have a feeling this might depend on GameObject duplication.

Maybe your GameObject (polling for input) has "DontDestroyOnLoad" called on it and you have a second one in your Game Scene and forgot to remove the one from the MainMenu.

Comment: I have everyting in one scene, the game and menu. I don't using DontDestroyOnLoad anywhere. The "Start Game" button is simply reloading entire scene.

Comment: So on "Start Game", you just hide the menu and there's the Game behind it? Are you duplicating or instantiating any GameObject that might accidentally have a copy of the component polling for input?

Comment: Just found my bug. Calling input function second time from other script. Now works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found bug in my scripts (after I find out that I can click on Debug Log and trace the call) I was calling my Input function second time (not needed) from second player controlling script. Problem solved.